# Javascript date format 2012-04-01T23:00:00Z

Tags: jquery

I have the the following date format in my jQuery. But when I try to do a dateparse using the datepicker it states that the object is not supported. I take it that the date format is incorrect.

The following line works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. I get NaN returned as a result:

```
var newdate = getNewDate(value);

function getNewDate(dateValue) {
    var newDate = new Date(dateValue);
    var cDate  = newDate.getDate();
    var cMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1; // have to add one as January starts from 0
    var cYear = newDate.getFullYear();

    return cDate + "/" + cMonth + "/" + cYear;
};
```

When I do `getDate` it returns `NaN` for each of the gets, i.e. `getDate`, `getMonth` and `getFullYear`.

All I require is to get the date and return in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a date in long format from ATOM feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416296/parsing-a-date-in-long-format-from-atom-feed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MCXCn/)

```
var value = '2012-04-01T23:00:00Z';
var newdate = getNewDate(value);
alert(newdate);
function getNewDate(dateValue) {
    var newDate = new Date(dateValue.substring(0,dateValue.indexOf('T')).replace(/-/g,'/'));
    var cDate  = newDate.getDate();
    // have to add one as January starts from 0
    var cMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1; 
    var cYear = newDate.getFullYear(); 
    return cDate + "/" + cMonth + "/" + cYear;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split amd substring functions

function getNewDate(dateValue) {

```
var dataAarr = dateValue.split('-'); 


   return dataAarr[2].substring(0,2) + "/" + dataAarr[1] + "/" + dataAarr[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/justeric/nCE9u/58/)

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```