# Get date in yyyymmdd (20180328) format

Tags: javascript, date, format

1. Input Date in yyyymmdd (20180328) format.
2. Get list of two previous months date (yyyymmdd).
3. Output should be store in variable with format yyyymmdd so that I can use it later to run xyz in loop with all previous three months date.

Eg:
If I enter 20170828 ,then it will return me 
**20170828
20170728 
20170628** 
and I can use this outputs as input to xyz operation without calling xyz 3 separate times

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb javascript

Comment: OK, hold on....

Comment: You're asking 3 questions, all are duplicates of very frequently asked questions that already have plenty of answers here. And you should show your attempt at answering the question, see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Parsing: [*How to parse a string into a date object at JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277170/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-date-object-at-javascript). Add/subtract months: [*Javascript function to add X months to a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706125/javascript-function-to-add-x-months-to-a-date). Formatting: [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Thanks.. I'm waiting :)

Comment: @RobG , I've tried a lot using all previously asked question in this website and others too. I'm new to javascript and facing issue after implementing the solution mentioned in the forums that's why I've raised this question. Anyways Thanks for sharing above links.

Comment: So use those links to perform the operations you want to perform. If you have difficulty with a particular part, post a question on that. You need to post what you've tried and where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this should work:

```
let date = new Date();

let dt = {
  year: date.getFullYear(),
  month: date.getMonth() + 1,
  day: date.getDate()
};

meses = 1;

let printDate = dateX => {
  let d = {
    y: dateX.year,
    m: dateX.month < 10 ? "0" + dateX.month : dateX.month,
    d: dateX.day < 10 ? "0" + dateX.day : dateX.day
  };
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = d.y + d.m + d.d;
  document.body.appendChild(p);

  if(meses < 3){
    meses++;  
    printDate({year: dateX.year, month: +dateX.month-1, day: dateX.day});
  }
}

printDate(dt);
```

This is a bit dangerous because of the global variable there, but it does the job.  **https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/0kyL5L1e/**

Comment: It's returning 20180329
20180229
20180129 , but feb month only has 28 days in 2018. Thanks for giving me idea.

Comment: Yes, it just takes the month without actually checking it as a date.