# If current date and time is greater (after) than X

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I am trying to create an if statement that can check today's date and time and if it's greater than a predefined date and time, do something. I'm looking to do this in vanilla JS only and get it to work in IE.

This is the basic working code for Chrome.

```
var ToDate = new Date()

if (new Date("2018-11-30 05:00").getTime() > ToDate.getTime()) {
  alert("true")
} else {
  alert("false")
}
```

How can I make something like this work in IE?

```
if (new Date("2018-11-30 05:00").getTime() > ToDate.getTime()) {
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @mauron85 Chrome but hoping to find a solution that works in all major desktop + mobile browsers...

Comment: Your example is working for me.

Comment: Working here too.

Comment: @mauron85—then you didn't try Safari.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

On firefox and chrome there are no issues with it. On Internet Explorer it's false.

On IE (or in general) the string needs to be an [RFC2822 or ISO 8601 formatted date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Example:

```
new Date("2018-11-29T19:15:00.000Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need portable solution (eg. support older Internet Explorer) I would use [this constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Keep in mind that `monthIndex` starts from 0 (January).

Test:

```
function assertTrue(exp, message) {
   if (exp === false) {
     message = message || 'Assertion failed';
     alert(message);
     throw message;
   }
}

function testShouldPassForDatesInTheFuture() {
    var ToDate = new Date(2018, 10, 29);
    assertTrue(new Date(2018, 10, 30).getTime() > ToDate.getTime());
}

function testShouldPassForDatesInThePast() {
    var ToDate = new Date(2018, 10, 29);
    assertTrue(new Date(2018, 10, 28).getTime() < ToDate.getTime());
}

testShouldPassForDatesInThePast();
testShouldPassForDatesInThePast();
alert('All test passed');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append 'T00:00:00.000Z' to your date.

```
new Date("2018-11-30" + 'T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Full code is below:

```js
var ToDate = new Date()

if (new Date("2018-11-30" + 'T00:00:00.000Z').getTime() > ToDate.getTime()) {
  alert("true")
} else {
  alert("false")
}
```

Comment: The OP says "*if it's greater than a predefined date and time*", so it's not a simple matter of adding a fixed time string. Also, this treats the date as UTC whereas it's much more common to treat date-only strings as local (although ECMAScript requires YYYY-MM-DD to be treated as UTC, so adding "T00:00:00Z" does nothing, except for Safari, which is another matter…).

Comment: Adding "T00:00:00Z" is just a way to simply show how we can convert time to UTC. Its easy to substitute it with another time if timing matters otherwise we can have "T00:00:00Z as default. The OP has internet-explorer tag as well so I assumed this is an IE related question. I tested the original code on IE9 as well as modern browsers. IE9 returns correct answer only if I added "T00:00:00Z.

Comment: The OP has a string like "2018-11-30 05:00", which should most probably be treated as local, not UTC. The simple solution is to not use the built–in parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm is not supported by ECMAScript, so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari, for example:

```
new Date("2018-11-30 05:00")
```

returns an invalid date.

You can first parse the string manually, either with a bespoke function (e.g. [*How to parse a string into a date object at JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277170/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-date-object-at-javascript)) or a library, then you can compare the result with `new Date()` as for [*Compare two dates with JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript).

A simple parse function is not difficult:

```js
/* Parse string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss to a Date
 * All parts after YYYY-MM are optional, milliseconds ignored
 */
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]||1, b[3]||0, b[4]||0, b[5]||0);
}

["2018-11-23 17:23",
 "2019-01",
 "2020-12-31 23:59:59"].forEach(s => {
   console.log(`${s} => ${parseDate(s).toString()}`);
 });
```

Then you can compare dates using `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.

In this case, a date like "2018-01-01" will be considered past at any time after 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000.

Alternatively, since the string is similar to ISO 8601 format, you can compare the parts of the string with a similarly formatted string for today:

```js
// Return date string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format
// Only return as many parts as len, or all 6 if missing
function formatDate(d, len) {
  var parts = [d.getFullYear(), '-'+d.getMonth()+1, '-'+d.getDate(), ' '+d.getHours(), ':'+d.getMinutes(), ':'+d.getSeconds()];
  var spacer = ['-','-',' ',':',':'];
  len = len || 6;
  return parts.splice(0, len).join('');
}

['2018-06-30 12:04',
 '2018-10',
 '2018-12-15 03:14:45',
 '2019-01-01',
 '2020-12-15 03:14:45'].forEach(s => {
   console.log(`${s} has passed? ${s < formatDate(new Date(), s.split(/\D/).length)}`);
});
```

In this case, 2018-01-01 will be equal to any date generated on that day, and "2018-01" will be equal to any date generated in January 2018. It's up to you whether you use `<` or `<=` for the comparison.

So you need to consider carefully where you draw the boundary between earlier and later and adjust the logic accordingly.