# Formatting a Date string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, date, format

I have a date string which looks like this:

> Thu Feb 09 2012 01:50:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

And I basically need to re-format it to be 2 strings (one for date and one for time).

The date format needs to be:

> m-d-Y (01-16-2012)

and the time should be

> H:i (10:30)

Comment: My "H:i" and "m-d-Y" are from PHP, I didn't know the correct ones in JS. Sorry.

Comment: This might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206790/best-javascript-date-parser-formatter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).  It is an excellent JavaScript library for parsing dates.  (Making use of jQuery for cleanliness)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = "Thu Feb 09 2012 01:50:00 GMT+0000";
var dout = Date.parse(d);
$("#date").text(dout.toString('M-d-yyyy')); 
$("#time").text(dout.toString('HH:mm'));     
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

I believe DateJS extends the native JavaScript Date Object and might not be what you want.  I am pretty sure MomentJS ( is was inspired by DateJS ) does not extend the native Date Object.

Check out the docs for Moment.js, this should do the trick for you: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string+format

var foo = moment( stringDateValue , 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm');

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the built-in [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, but [`Datejs`](http://www.datejs.com/) can do this.

Using Datejs' [`toString`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) method:

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')); // 01-16-2012
console.log(now.toString('HH:mm')); // 10:30
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/b3wgR/3

EDIT: If your date is from a string, Datejs can [parse](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse) it for you.

```
var str = "Thu Feb 09 2012 01:50:00 GMT+0000";
var date = Date.parse(str);
console.log(date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')); // 02-09-2012
console.log(date.toString('HH:mm')); // 01:50
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RY5jb/

Comment: The only thing that may be wrong is that I don't generate the date string, how would I pass my date string to that function? (My date string will be stored as a var)

Comment: @DarkMantis: Check my edit, `Datejs` can parse the string into a `Date` object

Answer (score 2):

```
    var td = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var month_name = new Array(12);
    month_name[0] = "January";
    month_name[1] = "February";
    month_name[2] = "March";
    month_name[3] = "April";
    month_name[4] = "May";
    month_name[5] = "June";
    month_name[6] = "July";
    month_name[7] = "August";
    month_name[8] = "September";
    month_name[9] = "October";
    month_name[10] = "November";
    month_name[11] = "December"; 

   document.getElementById("TodayDate").innerHTML = weekday[td.getDay()] + ", " + month_name[td.getMonth()] + " " + td.getDate() + ", " + td.getFullYear();
```

Now output is like :
Thursday, May 22, 2014

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/satishverma143/xSAbK/

Answer (score 1):

```
//example: dateFormater("D, M n, Y h:ft", new Date(), 2)
//results: a formated date two days from now -> Sunday, February 10, 2013 3:07pm
//today is Friday 2/8/13
function dateFormater (mod, nDate, addDay) {
    var daysFull = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var daysAbbr = ["Sun.", "Mon.", "Tue.", "Wed.", "Thu.", "Fri.", "Sat."];
    var monthsFull = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthsAbbr = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."];
    var moddt = "";
    var tmp;
    
    //add days to date (use -1 to subtract days
    if (typeof addDay !== 'undefined') nDate.setDate(nDate.getDate() + addDay);
    
    var dateMod = mod.split("");
    for (el in dateMod) {
        switch(dateMod[el]) {
            //Delimiters: ,=, /=/ " "=" " :=:
            case ",":
                moddt += dateMod[el];
                break;
            case "/":
                moddt += dateMod[el];
                break;
            case " ":
                moddt += dateMod[el];
                break;
            case ":":
                moddt += dateMod[el];
                break;
            
            //Month: M=January m=Jan. J=01 j=1
            case "M":
                moddt += monthsFull[nDate.getMonth()];
                break;
            case "m":
                moddt += monthsAbbr[nDate.getMonth()];
                break;
            case "J":
                tmp = nDate.getDate();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                break;
            case "j":
                tmp = nDate.getDate();
                moddt += tmp.toString();
                break;

            //Day: D=Monday d=Mon. N=01 n=1
            case "D":
                moddt += daysFull[nDate.getDay()];
                break;
            case "d":
                moddt += daysAbbr[nDate.getDay()];
                break;
            case "N":
                tmp = nDate.getDate();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                break;
            case "n":
                tmp = nDate.getDate();
                moddt += tmp.toString();
                break;

            //Year: Y=2013 y=13
            case "Y":
                moddt += nDate.getFullYear();
                break;
            case "y":
                tmp = nDate.getFullYear();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                moddt += tmp.substr(2, 2);
                break;

            //Hour: H=08 h=8 Military: Z=14 z=01
            case "H":
                tmp = nDate.getHours();
                if (tmp > 12) tmp -= 12;
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                    break;
            case "h":
                tmp = nDate.getHours();
                if (tmp > 12) tmp -= 12;
                moddt += tmp.toString();
                break;
            case "Z":
                tmp = nDate.getHours();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                break;
            case "z":
                tmp = nDate.getHours();
                moddt += tmp.toString();
                break;

            //Minute: f=08
            case "f":
                tmp = nDate.getMinutes();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                break;

            //Seconds: s=08
            case "s":
                tmp = nDate.getSeconds();
                tmp = tmp.toString();
                if (tmp.length == 1) {
                    moddt += "0" + tmp;
                } else {
                    moddt += tmp;
                }
                break;

            //AM/PM: T=AM/PM t=am/pm q=a/p
            case "T":
                if (nDate.getHours() > 11) {
                    moddt += "PM";
                } else {
                    moddt += "AM";
                }
                break;
            case "t":
                if (nDate.getHours() > 11) {
                    moddt += "pm";
                } else {
                    moddt += "am";
                }
                break;
            case "q":
                if (nDate.getHours() > 11) {
                    moddt += "p";
                } else {
                    moddt += "a";
                }
                break;
        }       
    }
    return moddt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a polyfill for new Date().format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");

it will return a string with whatever format you want

https://github.com/UziTech/js-date-format