# JQuery format date from MySQL. How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following date format in a MySQL database and was wondering what would be the best method to reformat this date and output what I have in mind.

MySQL: 2012-04-12

Desired Output: Thursday, April 12 2012

Perhaps I could format it in the MySQL query?
Or with Java script?

Could anyone provide a sample of both so I could learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to do this:

- With MySQL, using `DATE_FORMAT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
- With PHP, using `strtotime` and `date`: `date('J, M d Y', strtotime($yourdate))`
- With JavaScript, splitting the date at "-" and then creating your date again with `new Date()`
- Also (like explained by t0s6i), with JavaScript, you can use the library [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) to do something like this: `date = moment("2012-04-12", "DDDD, MMMM DD YYYY");`.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ent_date, '%W %M %d %Y') FROM tblentry

Answer (score 3):

Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

e.g. var day = moment("2012-04-12", "DDDD, MMMM DD YYYY");

Answer (score 0):

For formatting in javascript using jquery, loo at this other post.

[Best JavaScript Date Parser & Formatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206790/best-javascript-date-parser-formatter)

I would probably format with the code actually pulling the date form MySql.
What language are you using? php, asp, java...?

Comment: PHP. I wouldn't use ASP if it meant the cure to cancer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a convenient class for reading dates in a specific format:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$result = mysql_query("select date_column from table_name limit 1");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d')->format('jS M Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is usually to format the value with the PHP side just before outputting it:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['the_date']);
echo $date->format('J, M d Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an date with mysql, it's you receive it in Php no?

for optimize your performance, use the native php date function to convert your mysql date , it's easy:

read just the official PHP doc => http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Php treatments as more fast than javascript treatments.

Answer (score 0):

From javascript you can format your date using below function, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CZqTJ/1/)

**Note:** The below function additionally displays sup for date (ex: 3rd, 12th e.t.c). Remove all the `if..else if` in below code if you don't want it.

```
function formatDate(d) {

    var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

    var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    var curr_day = d.getDay();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var sup = "";
    if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date == 31) {
        sup = "st";
    } else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22) {
        sup = "nd";
    } else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23) {
        sup = "rd";
    } else {
        sup = "th";
    }

    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

    return  d_names[curr_day] + " " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + sup + "  " + curr_year;

}
```

**Reference:** [Javascript Date formatting](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/getting_current_time_using_javascript.php3) (above is modified version of Format #5)