# javascript error in converting date to long format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following date which i convert to a long format. This works fine in chrome but i get an error when i work with firefox. The date object says invalid date. What is wrong with the below code when it just works fine on chrome?

```
startdate= "2013-08-23 14:59"
alert(startdate);
startdate = new Date(startdate);
alert(startdate);     //Invalid date
startdate = startdate.getTime();
alert(startdate);     //NAN
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hulk_hulk/kvtW3/

Comment: Where is `startdate` defined?

Comment: so i have corrected it

Comment: If you are not against using a library I would have to recommend [link](http://momentjs.com/). This would allow you to validate and format your dates cross-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way ..

```
startdate="2013-08-23 14:59:00"
var a=startdate.split(" ");
var d=a[0].split("-");
var t=a[1].split(":");
startdate= new Date(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2]);
alert(startdate);     //correct date
startdate = startdate.getTime();
alert(startdate);
```

hope is useful and Works in IE FF Chrome etc.

Comment: If you able to add seconds in your time then try this way , another way is remove t[2] from date object ..

Answer (score 2):

[The ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) describes that [`Date`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) constructor internally uses [`Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), which accepts [*Date Time String Format*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), which is simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format.

`"2013-08-23 14:59"` doesn't matches with that format, so Firefox fails to parse. But some implementation can parse additional formats, for example Chrome in your case.

Consider using [JavaScript date parser/formatter library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206790/best-javascript-date-parser-formatter) for browser compatibility. You can easily find millions of libraries from SO/Google.

### From the spec

15.9.3.2 new Date (value):

> If Type(v) is String, then Parse v as a date, in exactly the same
>   manner as for the parse method (15.9.4.2); let V be the time value for
>   this date.

15.9.4.2 Date.parse (string):

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String
>   according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format
>   (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the
>   function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or
>   implementation-specific date formats.

15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format:

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based
>   upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is
>   as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

Answer (score 1):

Use a library to handle consistent parsing of dates across multiple platforms.  Like this one.

https://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox wants new Date(), try in this way:

```
    startdate= "2013-08-23 14:59"
    alert(startdate);

    startdate = new Date(2013,08,23,14,59,00,00);

    alert(startdate);     //Invalid date
    startdate = startdate.getTime();
    alert(startdate);     //NAN
```

Answer (score 0):

> **The Javascript date support many formats try any of these..!!**

Changing the code to this may Help

```
startdate= "23 09 2013, 14:59:00"
alert(startdate);
startdate = new Date(startdate);
alert(startdate);     //Invalid date
startdate = startdate.getTime();
alert(startdate);
```

You can also set values in the following format 
try in any of this format

```
date1 = new Date("25 Dec, 1995 23:15:00")
date2 = new Date("2009 06 12,12:52:39")
date3 = new Date("20 09 2006,12:52:39")
```

look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for JavaScript date details